# Process input seems buggy in Emacs on OS X

Tags: osx, process, subprocess

I have a process that I'm trying to send input to on OS X. I'm using Emacs' builtin functions for doing this: `process-send-string` and `process-send-region`. However, it seems that there are issues when doing this on OS X. Specifically, it seems that I cannot send a process more than 1 KiB of data. To demonstrate what I mean, here's an example.

I started an Elisp REPL with `M-x ielm` and ran the following command:

```
ELISP> (start-process "cat" "*cat*" "cat")
#<process cat>
```

Then I ran this (no reason I'm using `f`; it's just a letter I thought of):

```
ELISP> (process-send-string (get-process "cat") "fff\n")
```

And I got what I expected in the `*cat*` buffer:

```
fff
```

Now, what if I send this:

```
(process-send-string (get-process "cat") "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff\n")
```

That is a string of 1,024 `f` characters (which is 1 KiB), followed by a newline so that `cat` knows that's the end of the input line. That is a grand total of 1,025 bytes which is just over 1 KiB. When I run the above command, all I get in the `*cat*` buffer is:

```
^G
```

It is highlighted so I know that it's a control character. Specifically, this is the ASCII `BEL` which is number 7. I guess this means that Emacs is getting an error in its `write` call to `cat`. The `cat` process is still alive, though.

According to `errno.h`, 7 is the error number for the POSIX `E2BIG` error. `E2BIG` is described like so in `man 2 intro`:

```
7 E2BIG Arg list too long.  The number of bytes used for the argument
and environment list of the new process exceeded the limit NCARGS
(specified in <sys/param.h>).
```

However, `NCARGS` is defined as `ARG_MAX` in `param.h`. `ARG_MAX` is defined as `256 * 1024` in `syslimits.h`, which is 256 KiB. So it seems that I shouldn't be having this problem since my input size is well within the bounds. However, I notice the following settings which are also defined in the system headers:

```
syslimits.h:81:#define  MAX_CANON        1024   /* max bytes in term canon input line */
syslimits.h:82:#define  MAX_INPUT        1024   /* max bytes in terminal input */
...
syslimits.h:91:#define  PATH_MAX         1024   /* max bytes in pathname */
...
dirent.h:100:#define __DARWIN_MAXPATHLEN    1024
...
_types/_fd_def.h:42:#define __DARWIN_FD_SETSIZE 1024
```

All of these constants are set to 1024. I wonder if one of them is causing this errant behavior with `cat` described above. However, this doesn't happen in the terminal. It seems to be specific to Emacs.

Also, as a sanity check, I tested the exact same code in Emacs on Linux and found that everything behaves as expected. I can send well over 1 KiB to a `cat` process on Linux without a hitch. So is this an Emacs bug or an OS X bug? And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, but you can circumvent it by creating your process with `process-connection-type` bound to nil so it doesn't use a tty but a pipe.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, that fixes the problem and clears things up. I wasn't sure whether I was dealing with a pty or a pipe, but that makes much more sense now. It makes a lot more sense that the `^G` came from the pty complaining. If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how to fix it (I really mean it: I've tried to fix this bug in the past, but my POSIX-fu is not strong enough), but you can circumvent it by creating your process with `process-connection-type` bound to nil so it doesn't use a tty but a pipe.